# Can I reset a counter in after effects expression?

Tags: expression, counter, reset, after-effects

I want to reset counter to 0. For example: 
In a text layer expression displayed value of time. When time is 3s displayed value must reset to 0 and increasing again. I can't use for counter value new variable, because it redefines in every frame. I can't store a variable in another text layer.

"An expression is a small piece of code, much like a script ... that evaluates to a single value for a single layer property at a specific point in time."

How can I do this? I want to see a displayed value like this "0...1...2...0...1...2...0...etc"

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Maybe it's can help someone. 
time % 3